# $a_{ij}=w_j^Tw_i$, Matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ is positive semi-definite

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Given $a_{ij}=w_j^Tw_i$, for $w_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $1 \leq i \leq n$, Then Matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ is positive definite.

I calculated $x^TAx$, and expression I came up with
$(w_{1}^Tw_{1} x_1^2+\dots+w_{n}^Tw_{n} x_{n}^2)+2\{(x_{1}x_{2}w_{1}^Tw_{2}+\dots+x_{1}x_{n}w_{1}^Tw_{n})+(x_{2}x_{3}w_{2}^Tw_{3}+\dots+x_{2}x_{n}w_{2}^Tw_{n})+\dots+(x_{n-1}x_nw_{n-1}^Tw_{n})\}$.

First bracket terms are positive. Could not proceed further. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

Let $W =\begin{bmatrix} w_1 & \ldots w_n \end{bmatrix}$, we can write $A=W^TW$.

Comment: Thanks I understand.